# Can I poll my USB HID device without first sending a command

Tags: usb, protocols, pic, hid

I was able to make a working HID USB stack on my "StartUSB for PIC" board for the 18F2550 microcontroller. I based it on one of the MLA libraries, which was made for the 18F45K50 (MLA 2018_11_26, hid_custom, picdem_fs_usb_k50.x), but I converted it to work with the 18F2550 (there might have been easier ways, but only learned to work with PIC about 1 month ago). On the host side, I'm using LibUsbDotNet (also here, there might be easier ways - the documentation on this library really sucks) on a Windows 10 machine.

I'm using the HID class, full speed, and all seems to work. Although, I get some random errors on the host PC (see below), but doing one close/re-open cycle on the host side when getting the error is kind of solving it. Dirty, but it works. So I kind of ignore this now.

*Win32Error:Win32Error:GetOverlappedResult Ep 0x01*

*995:The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.*

I'm not an expert on USB (yet). But all examples I'm seeing are based on 1) you send first a command to the device and 2) then you retrieve the answer from the device. I did some performance tests, and see that this indeed shows that I can do about 500 cycles/second. I think that is correct, because each cycle, sending command and retrieving answer, each takes 1 msec.

**But do I really need to send a command?** Can't I just keep reading endlessly, and when the device has somthing to say, it does send the data in an IN transaction, and when not it ignores which creates a timeout on the host side. That would mean that I can poll at 1000 cycles/second? Unfortunately, I have tried it by changing my implementation on the PIC, but I get very weird results. I think I have issues with suspend mode. That brings me to another question - how can I make the device get out of suspend mode (means that not the host, but the device should be triggering this event). I have searched the MLA library for command such as "wakeup", "resume", ... but couldn't find anything.

So, to summarize, 2 questions:

- **Conceptual:** Can I send data from device to host without being requested for it by a command from the host?
- **For PIC experts:** How can I have a device trigger for a wakeup from suspend mode?

Comment: In USB, every transfer is initiated from the host so the answer to the first question is no.

Comment: Yes, transfer is initiated from the host but there is no need for sending a command first. The host will poll all IN endpoints once every 1ms. If the endpoint has data available and is a bulk endpoint, the host will poll the endpoint again immediately if bandwidth allows.

Answer (score 0):

And indeed, the answer is Yes on the first question.

In the meantime, I found another link on the web that contains a Visual Studio C# implementation of a USB library including all the source files.

[If you're interested, this is the link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830856/Microchip-PIC-F-USB-Stack)

This C# host implementation works as a charm. Without sending a command to the device, I get notified immediately if a button is pressed. Great!

It also proofs that my earlier device implementation based on the original MicroChip MLA, is 100% correct. I stress tested the implementation by sending a "toggle LED command" as fast as I could, and I reach 1000 commands/second. Again great!

I think that LibUsbDotNet isn't that perfect after all. As I wrote above, I get rather unstable communication (Win32Error). But with this implementation, I don't get a single error, even after running for half an hour @ 1000 commands/second.

So for me, case closed.